# Idiomatic Angular form components

Tags: angular, forms, dry, angular-forms

I'm creating a form that uses Bootstrap input groups to allow the user to input percentages.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nothing fancy, but somewhat verbose, and I may want to add or modify how I handle percent inputs later, so I don't want to repeat this HTML block for every percent field on the form.  If I were doing React, I'd wrap it in a simple functional component and be done.

```
const PercentInput = props => (
  <div class="input-group">
    <input {...props} type="number" step="0.01">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Now I have a `PercentInput` that acts just like an `input` (except for a different DOM) and that doesn't need to know or care how it's used, because it can blindly pass any and all props down to the `input` node that it wraps and imitates.

Creating an equivalent component in Angular seems a lot more complicated. As I understand it, I would have to do the following:

- Implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) (3-4 methods and 2 event handlers), so I can work with Angular forms (as described [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2) or [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html))
- Explicitly handle any `<input>` attributes that I care about, because [Angular doesn't support passing unknown props](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47297089/25507).

This seems overly complicated, which makes me think that I'm stuck in a React mindset and am missing or misunderstanding how an idiomatic Angular application would do this.

What's a typical clean, idiomatic way of approaching this in Angular?

Comment: Yes, basically what you want to do is isolate some part of the HTML with the underlying logic as a component. So component is way to go. As you said: "Implement ControlValueAccessor (3-4 methods and 2 event handlers)...". This is what I usually do and it's allow you to use [(ngModel)] as you would do for the regular input. Even this solution might look "bulky" in fact it's not. However I agree that React provides more accurate way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a component which has a dictionary for an Input property:

**percent-input.component.ts**

```
import { 
    Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input 
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'percent-input',
    templateUrl: 'percent-input.component.html'
})
export class PercentInputComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('inputField') inputField: ElementRef;
    @Input() props: { [key: string]: string };
    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (this.props) {
            Object.keys(this.props).forEach( attr => {
                this.inputField.nativeElement.setAttribute(attr, this.props[attr]);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**percent-input.component.html**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" #inputField class="form-control" step="0.01">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Use it like this**

```
<percent-input [props]="{ style: 'background-color: yellow'  }" ></percent-input>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1e3tj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)